# laravelのauth、とguest、の判断の仕方について

Tags: php, laravel

userとadminが別のルートでログインできる機能を実装しています。ほとんどlaravel5.2標準のauth機能を拡張したものです。

```
php artisan route:list

|        | GET|HEAD | admin/home                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminHomeController@index                  | web,auth:admin  |
|        | POST     | admin/login                  |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuthController@login                  | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/login                  |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/logout                 |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuthController@logout                 | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth:user   |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest:user  |
|        | POST     | login                        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest:user  |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                       |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web             |
|        | POST     | password/email               |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest       |
|        | POST     | password/reset               |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?}      |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                     |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest:user  |
|        | POST     | register                     |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest:user  |
```

admin guardを追加しています。

ログインだったり、非認証ユーザー（admin)をそれぞれのlogin画面にリダイレクトするところまではできたのですが、以下のif文の中の、Auth::guest()が理解できていなく困っています。

```
app.blade.php
...
@if (Auth::guest())
         <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
@else
         <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                 {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
           </a>

           <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
@endif
....
```

ルートでは、home、admin/home画面はauthで、それ以外がguestだと認識しているのですが、ログイン後のhome画面でも、上のAuth::guest()がtrueになってしまう状態で、思っているビューが表示されません。
似たような問題を解決されたことがある方、どうかご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth::check() や Auth::guest() は config/auth.php で設定したデフォルトの guard が使われます。

```
Auth::guard('admin')->guest()
```

のように guard を指定してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます、無事multiauth実装できました！！